# VS2015 Update 2 message: "Low memory detected. Full solution analysis disabled for this solution."

Tags: memory, visual-studio-2015

I just updated Visual Studio 2015 with Update 2.

Now, after few hours of working fine, I received: "Low memory detected. Full solution analysis disabled for this solution." that appears on the top of my editor dock panel of VS2015.

I saw that a bug had been reported at [Microsoft Connect](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/2544045/low-memory-detected-full-solution-analysis-disabled-for-this-solution-on-roslyn-code-analyzer-enabled-projects).

Notes:

- I'm using Resharper.
- My solution is pretty big, ~32 projects in it.

If anybody has a workaround or a hint on what to do to solve this, please let me know.

**Update:** I have pretty much the same feelings as Anders Forsgren (first comment). That's sounds to me a good summary of the situation.

**Update 2 (2016-04-20)** I recently (3 days ago) made a big clean up of my Framework.Net installed packages (from "Programs and features") where I removed about 20-30 packages. Some were in Russian. I also re-installed Visual Studio and ReSharper. All of that seems to have add some stability to my environment (less or no more freezes -> time will tell).
Also, there is a new (2016-04-19) [.NET Framework Repair Tool Version](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2016/04/19/introducing-the-microsoft-net-framework-repair-tool-version-1-3/) that came out recently. Perhaps it could help to fix some of our problems, if any related?

**Update 3** After some tests and read some peoples text. It seems that it is not related to .Net framework itself or Resharper. It seems to be related to VS2015 itself, probably Roslyn. I didn't success to remove Roslyn/CodeAnalysis from VS2015, it appears to be an essential part. It sounds like we will have to wait for a Microsoft fix to have a stable environment.

**Update 4 (2016-04-26)** See John Atwood answer. Lots of information. I just started to test its answer. Update 3 should solve this issue (when available ???).

**Update 5 (2016-04-26 + 6 hours)** After 1 restart done by VS itself, one incredible slowness and also one message "Low memory...", I could confirm that disabling Full Solution analysis does not fix the problem, at least on my machine. I currently don't know any fix/workaround that works on my machine.

**Update 6 (2016-06-15)** Mladen Mihajlovic woke me up. I just realized that I forgot to tell about the availability of VS2015 Update 3 RC (please note that I think it is the second release: Update 3 RC2). It is available since june 7 at [MSDN](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/news/releasenotes/vs2015-update3-vs), RC1 = 14.0.25401.00 while RC2 = 14.0.25402.00. It sounds to be a lot more stable (I highly recommend it).

Comment: I think this is a workaround for problem that existed earlier, but before update2 it didn't disable it automatically, instead the performance became horrible. The bottom line is that for a big solution (probably in terms of code size rather than number of projects), full solution analysis is still impractical so you simply don't want it. Now that happens automatically. Switching it off *is* the workaround for the problem. The Roslyn team may be working on a solution. I have a 100+ project solution with 50k types, Update1 was unusable and in Update2 I get the error directly on solution load.

Comment: Thanks a lots for the information. It probably explains why my VS2015 Update 1 was freezing once in a while too. Now at least, there is a fallback  and we can continue to work. I hope Roslyn team will find a solution quickly :-) !

Comment: @AndersForsgren, If I understand you right, you said to switch off VS2015 C# code analysis??? How do you do that?

Comment: @AndersForsgren, I found How to enable/disable Code Analysis in solution properties. Is that what you recommend and if so, what settings do you recommend (Microsoft Managed Minimum Rules)?

Comment: I'm also getting the same issue with VS 2015 Update 2 with a solution that has 50 projects. 

In the end, VS crashes and looking into the event logs it shows the message "System.OutOfMemoryException: Exception of type 'System.OutOfMemoryException' was thrown.". Full stacktrace in this gist: https://gist.github.com/willl/ea6e3ea8bb4bdb1840d45087daa6073d

Comment: Same is with us. 40 projects.

Comment: @WilliamL, How do you get the stack trace of the crash. I think I can see appropriate event in the event log. But I can't find the Report Id associate with the event. I looked for a Report.wer at C:\Users\[user]\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\WER\ReportArchive\AppCrash_devenv.exe_[ID] or at: C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\WER\ReportArchive without success ??? There is no stack trace???

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because there is an existing microsoft connect issue.

Comment: @EricOuellet The stacktrace was in the event log for me.

Comment: https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/2544045/low-memory-detected-full-solution-analysis-disabled-for-this-solution-on-roslyn-code-analyzer-enabled-projects

Comment: I also have this issue, with an embarrassingly small number of projects (just 28).  Quite a few people on the connect issue state they're also using ReSharper.  Are people getting this issue that DON'T have ReSharper (or CodeRush...other tools are of course available).

Comment: @DrGriff, That' a really good question. I hope that Microsoft will soon find the source of the problem, either if it is Resharper... and tell peoples about the cause and how to fix it. Or, anybody else :-) !

Comment: I have VS2015 Update 2, but I don't have ReSharper or any other add-in tools. My solution has 20 very large projects. It takes a while to build. But, I don't get the error. In fact, it seems to be working better than when it was in VS2012. Intellisense is more responsive, etc.

Comment: @ChrisFannin, Very interesting. It seems to target ReSharper but last week I removed around 20-30 Microsoft packages (from  "Control Panel" - "Programs and Features") related to Framework.Net, mostly packages in different languages. I re-installed VS2015 and ReSharper ... since then, everything seems OK. If the bug come from previously installed things in wrong order that would explain why Microsoft take so much time to fix it (they could be unable to reproduce the bug in their environment). But I need times to confirm this behavior (all ok). Thanks for sharing info, that was a missing part.

Comment: @ChrisFannin, I will wait a week or so and verify if my environment is more stable. If so, I will inform here and Microsoft about what I have found. It should be quite easy to see stability, because my VS2015 Update 2 is always restarted by itself on each morning since I updated to Update 2 but this morning it was fine !!! But I will wait a bit more to be sure...

Comment: @ChrisFannin, Hey! I just realized that ReSharper was disabled. I re-enabled it. I will do some tests during the week to try to isolate if the bug come from ReSharper.

Comment: Resharper always needs an update when VS changes.

Comment: @HansPassant, Thanks Hans, I verified after Update 2, that I had the latest version of Resharper. I verify ~once a week that I have the latest version of ReSharper. But I highly think that JetBrain advise us now when a new version is available.

Comment: I have the same issue. VS2015 upd. 2 + ReSharer (both updated). We have around 400 projects in solution. I only encountered this with ReSharper. But unfortunately I installed update 2 about at the same time as ReSharper. So I am not sure who is to blame. VS just runs out of the available memory for 32bit application. Having 64bit VS IDE could have helped. I have plenty of free memory to spare (64GB) -- so I hate applications telling me that they run out of memory.

Comment: Same message. My denenv process takes up to 2 378 MB (private working set). I know it's a LARGEADDRESSAWARE but it seem very large.

Comment: Same issue here. I also have Resharper installed. My desktop have 32GB RAM... that should not be the problem :)

Comment: It seems there is a fix for this issue in VS2015 update 3 as per the Microsoft Connect comments. (Actual bug post: https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/pull/11479)

Comment: @MladenMihajlovic, I don't know how to install from GitHub directly. Not sure it is possible? I think I will wait for an official patch to install and/or a real Update 3 package from Microsoft.

Comment: @EricOuellet There is an RC out for the patch, but I personally always wait for the release.

Comment: @MladenMihajlovic. Thanks alots. I run with it for 2 days now. Although not perfect, it really sounds to be a lots better. I didn't crash since it is installed which would have happen ~3-10 times with Update 2. I will add that information in my question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Few weeks now with update 3 available and nobody answering...

"Visual Studio Update 3" fix that issue and solve many others. A MUST !!!

I recommend to read this before installing Update 3: [Visual Studio 2015 Update 3 and .NET Core 1.0 Available Now](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/visualstudio/2016/06/27/visual-studio-2015-update-3-and-net-core-1-0-available-now/) from John Montgomery.

Direct Download link: [Visual Studio Update 3](https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=691129)

Answer (score 3):

After a very brief analysis it seems that issue can be related to CodeAnalysis implementation which is enabled by default and I could not find any configuration file option which can disable it.

Here are [reference search results](http://source.roslyn.codeplex.com/#Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Features/Shared/Options/RuntimeOptions.cs,183d2027d65299af,references).

I was however able to successfully disable CodeAnalysis VS plugin for the time being and it seems it made a difference in how smoothly VS runs.

The only change was to rename CodeAnalysis extension plugin folder from:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\CodeAnalysis
```

to

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\CodeAnalysis_disabled
```

This obviously will degrade VisualStudio feature set and possibly cause some side effects but since I'm using ReSharper's own alanylsis features, the VS CodeAnalysis was just excessive.

**Update:**

It looks like Microsoft.VisualStudio.CodeAnalysis.VCPlugin.dll is also added to GAC and protected from deletion by gacutil. To forcibly remove it from GAC following steps are required:

1. Delete the following registry key but save it first just in case:

> Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00
>
> [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\Installer\Assemblies\Global]
>       "Microsoft.VisualStudio.CodeAnalysis,version=\"14.0.0.0\",publicKeyToken=\"b03f5f7f11d50a3a\",processorArchitecture=\"MSIL\",fileVersion=\"14.0.23107.0\",culture=\"neutral\""=hex(7):6a,\
>         00,5f,00,65,00,7e,00,5a,00,61,00,47,00,71,00,2a,00,3f,00,6a,00,61,00,31,00,\
>         30,00,6e,00,66,00,70,00,4e,00,2d,00,44,00,54,00,65,00,73,00,74,00,54,00,6f,\
>         00,6f,00,6c,00,73,00,5f,00,65,00,6e,00,75,00,3e,00,39,00,42,00,21,00,4e,00,\
>         63,00,6a,00,24,00,58,00,70,00,45,00,42,00,75,00,6a,00,21,00,56,00,3d,00,2d,\
>         00,31,00,51,00,32,00,00,00,68,00,6a,00,4f,00,46,00,70,00,48,00,2d,00,24,00,\
>         4b,00,34,00,69,00,4f,00,68,00,33,00,72,00,60,00,65,00,62,00,28,00,36,00,43,\
>         00,6f,00,64,00,65,00,5f,00,41,00,6e,00,61,00,6c,00,79,00,73,00,69,00,73,00,\
>         5f,00,54,00,6f,00,6f,00,6c,00,73,00,5f,00,31,00,31,00,39,00,38,00,37,00,5f,\
>         00,78,00,38,00,36,00,5f,00,65,00,6e,00,75,00,3e,00,39,00,42,00,21,00,4e,00,\
>         63,00,6a,00,24,00,58,00,70,00,45,00,42,00,75,00,6a,00,21,00,56,00,3d,00,2d,\
>         00,31,00,51,00,32,00,00,00,00,00

2. Uninstall the assembly from GAC

> "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v10.0A\bin\NETFX 4.6 Tools\x64\gacutil.exe" /u "Microsoft.VisualStudio.CodeAnalysis, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a, processorArchitecture=MSIL" /f

It migt be also advised to move CodeAnalysis_disabled folder to another location as I cannot tell how VS MEF loader is implemented and where will it search for plugins.

Comment: Note: You can disable it by: Menu-ReSharper-Options-Code Inspection-"Enable code analysis".

Comment: I already tried your suggestion in the past (before Update 2) but it didn't prevent Visual Studio to freeze. It seems to happen less but still freeze. Monday, April 18 (3 days ago) I just uninstall 20-30 Framework.net package from "Program and features" and re-installed Visual Studio with Update 2 completely. It look like better, at least about freezing, because I haven't get the memory message for more than a week now. I will wait to be sure of the proper fix before accepting an answer. Thanks.

Comment: I don't mind really ReSharper's own code analysis. It actually makes sense that VS might still freeze with large codebases as it's a 32bit application which apparently after continuous growth of features needs a 64bit leap to cope with the memory constraints. Please treat my answer as a hint which helps to disable one memory and CPU hungry feature for the time being. Please also check the update.

Comment: I'm testing your solution. Thanks! Today, again, my VS2015 update 2 was restarted. Pretty agressive as a fix but if it works :-) !!! I will keep you informed of the behavior on my computer...

Comment: I just got the same message: "Low memory detected..." although I followed your instructions. I think Codeanalysis is still there. It seems that it is really hard to disable CodeAnalysis. I wonder if it is not critical for VS2015 to have it work properly (.. part of Roslyn).

Comment: Oops... can't modify my previous message... I think CodeAnalysis is still there (I see it from ProcessExplorer). It seems that it is really hard to disable CodeAnalysis. I also removed Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.dll from ...x86/VS2014/Common7/IDE/PrivateAssemblies but now Visual Studio won't load correctly. I think it is a Critical Part of VisualStudio, probaly into Roslyn which is required to also compile. It sounds that the only solution is to wait for a Microsoft fix...

Comment: I put back everything to normal. I only miss the registration to GAC which seems to be optional.

Comment: Thank you for sharing PrivateAssemblies find. So far I have not seen this error and using Process Hacker I regularly checked loaded managed modules and Microsoft.VisualStudio.CodeAnalysis was not on the list but only after removing from GAC. Maybe It can only mean my project is not big enough to trigger the issue often enough so I will experiment with SharpDevelope sources in spare time.

Answer (score 3):

A workaround for this issue is to disable Full solution analysis by going to Tools -> Options -> Text Editor -> C#(or Basic) -> Advanced -> Uncheck "Enable full solution analysis".

This appears to be a bug that the Rosyln team is working on https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/10365

Comment: Thanks, I just disabled VS Solution Analysis. Your link has a lot of useful information.

Comment: After 2 hours ==> no memory message but VS crash an restarted. But, I did not restarted after I disabled full solution analysis. Now it is done :-)!

Comment: I don't know if it fixes the memory message bug. But it certainly do not fix the memory problem, the inevitable slowness that occurs after a while (like 4 hours in my case). And eventually locks and die. A bug is still there. It does not fix the problem. (2016-04-26, 6 hours after trying the workaround).

Comment: Got it! "Low memory detected. Full solution analysis disabled for this solution" although my Full solution analysis was already disabled. It is so slow that I have to close and restart. Very productive!!! After an hour only.

Comment: Can anyone explain what "Enable full solution analysis" actually *does*? I already have it disabled but I'm also getting the "Low memory detected" message.

Answer (score 3):

I read some articles describing this problem as exceeding of virtual address space because some internal memory structure (List maybe) exceeds 2GB. 2GB is the default virtual address space for 32 bit processes like VS 2015. But [you can adjust it](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb613473%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to maximum of 3GB.

The solution I found is from [here](http://www.araxis.com/merge/documentation-windows/enabling-3gb-ram-on-32-bit-windows.en) :

```
Start▸All Programs▸Accessories▸right-click on Command Prompt▸Run as administrator

Run the following command:

bcdedit /set IncreaseUserVa 3072

Restart the computer.
```

This is not 100% solution because you can eventually run out of virtual address space even with 3GB of RAM for a process. After adjusting this switch VS stopped complaining about memory.

Comment: Thanks Ognyan, it could potentially give you a little bit more time but I don't know the downside of it. It there is none, why Microsoft wouldn't set that setting them self? I prefer to wait for a more robust solution. But perhaps some people will like it and try it. As a side note, it look like to be for 32 bits edition of Windows only (as written in the first sentence)??? I have Windows 7 64bits

Comment: My guess is that on a 32 bit system with only 4 GB of addressable memory there is no other option. Now I have a machine with 32G of RAM and there is no problem to give the process some more - the OS will have more than enough to use. You can read this on the [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb613473%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) : 

"On 32-bit editions of Windows, applications have 4 gigabyte (GB) of virtual address space available. The virtual address space is divided so that 2 GB is available to the application and the other 2 GB is available only to the system."

Comment: This sounds interesting! Will try it if/when vs2015 crashes again.  Thanks!

Comment: @OgnyanDimitrov, Windows released a new update which fixed VS2015 crashes.  As a result, I didn't try this solution.

Comment: @OgnyanDimitrov,  it was a general windows update.  Around May 9-12 they released a large amount of updates (around 30), and one of them (or several) was the fixer.  Make sure that all the windows updates are installed.

Answer (score 2):

My answer is to Close and Open Visual Studio.

I have "Enable full solution analysis" unchecked and I am still getting the Visual Studio message "Low memory detected. Full solution analysis disabled for this solution."  Visual Studio 2015 version is 14 Update 2.  I find that I have to close VS.

VS becomes unable to open TFS tasks and I cannot check in code unless I close and reopen VS.  Thankfully I have a new solid state hard drive so the VS close/open does not make me wait terribly long like it did before.  But still a disappointing hassle.

Comment: Thanks but that's what i'm doing already. I'm looking for a less disturbing solution :-) !

Answer (score 0):

I had been putting up with this problem for a while. I would see the memory usage climb steadily when working with TypeScript files, leading to an eventual crash. If this could be your situation, check if you have rxjs anywhere in your project. If the version is 5.0.0-beta.2, then upgrade to 5.0.0-beta.3 (or higher) to fix it.

More details: https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/7344#issuecomment-198392320

Comment: I only work with WPF.Do you talk about a reference? If yes, I never referenced rxjs anywhere in any of my projects.

Answer (score 0):

I wish I had a magic bullet. But here is what has helped me, but now always solves the problem.  VS2015 Update 2. Resharper 2016.1.1. All projects are vNEXT.

1. In Resharper --> Options --> Code Inspection --> Settings.  Add as many the wwwroot folder.  I also added each folder unter wwwroot as it didn't seem to cascade.  In File Masks, add any framework *.js or *.css (ie *.min.js, *jquery.js, *angular.js, *.min.css).  This step helped cut down on the "Loading source files" that resharper does when I build js/css with Gulp, Grunt for publish.
2. This is not ideal, but when I am writing code and don't plan on testing, I will Unload all of the projects that I am not using, usually in test.  This seems to cut down on the 'Managed Memory' that resharper/vs uses.
3. Lastly, and sort of annoying is that I NEVER look at files under the bower_components in VS Solution explorer. I find that going to the folder directly and using something like VSCODE for JS/JSON viewing saves me time and frustration.  It leads me to believe that although node_modules and bower_components are 'ignored' they aren't actually ignored or it has something to do with the sheer number of files in a project directory.

I await a solution that is 100%, but I hope these help.

Comment: I am updating my experience.  I disabled ReSharper Tools --> Options. Installed CodeMaid.  I still got the error of Low Memory.  It did take longer to get the error, but I don't think this is a Resharper problem, but do think that Resharper makes it happen more quickly.  No solution here yet, but I am happy that it's not Resharper's fault (per se).